# Segmentation fault in mono using pinvoke on liblvm2app.so

Tags: mono, pinvoke, rhel, lvm

I'm trying to write a c# program in mono to get information about the vgs (volume groups), lvs (logical volumes) and pvs (physical volumes).
I'm using a centOS7 system.
To get information about lvm, an API is defined (https://sourceware.org/git/?p=lvm2.git;a=blob;f=liblvm/lvm2app.h).
The example program in c++ works perfectly (https://www.redhat.com/archives/lvm-devel/2010-September/msg00025.html) with the API linked above.
But i'm having trouble, using pinvoke for the API calls from my c# program.

I have managed to get version data.
Therefore i assume, pinvoking the library is possible.

lvm2app.h

Wrapper class:

```
public class liblvm2wrapper
{
    [DllImport ("liblvm2app.so")]
    public static extern IntPtr lvm_init (IntPtr system_dir);

    [DllImport ("liblvm2app.so")]
    public static extern IntPtr lvm_errmsg (IntPtr libh);

    [DllImport ("liblvm2app.so", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern IntPtr lvm_library_get_version ();

    [DllImport ("liblvm2app.so", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern IntPtr lvm_vg_open(IntPtr libh, [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string vgname, [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string mode, int flags);

    [DllImport ("liblvm2app.so")]
    public static extern void lvm_quit (IntPtr libh);
}
```

Main

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          IntPtr lvmHandle = liblvm2.lvm_init(IntPtr.Zero);
          if(lvmHandle == IntPtr.Zero) return;

          IntPtr versionPtr = liblvm2wrapper.lvm_library_get_version();
          string version = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(versionPtr); // works

          // segFault occurs at the next line of code, if the name describes an existing vg
          // bash: line 1: 43812 Segmentation fault (core dumped) '/usr/bin/mono' --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:51779 "home/user/Documents/test/bin/x64/Debug/test.exe"
          IntPtr vgHandle = liblvm2wrapper.lvm_vg_open(lvmHandle , "volume_group", "r", 0); 
          if(vgHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
          {
              // if the string ("volume_group") passed to the function lvm_vg_open does not describe ane existing volume group, an empty pointer is returned and a valid error message is obtained calling the function below (lvm_errmsg)
              Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(liblvm2wrapper.lvm_errmsg(lvmHandle)));
          }
          liblvm2wrapper.lvm_quit(lvmHandle);
    }
}
```

From what i have heard, segmentation faults should be analized using gdb.
I followed the example from http: //pastebin.com/Kza9kemJ (can't post a third link, cause that's a new account.

and got the following output:

```
[root@vm user]# gdb --args mono '/home/user/Documents/test/bin/x64/Debug/test.exe' 
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-64.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/mono-sgen...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
warning: File "/usr/bin/mono-sgen-gdb.py" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load:/usr/bin/mono-gdb.py".
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/bin/mono-sgen-gdb.py
line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/mono /home/user/Documents/test/bin/x64/Debug/test.exe
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffee916700 (LWP 43646)]
2.02.130(2)-RHEL7 (2015-10-14)
[Thread 0x7fffee916700 (LWP 43646) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 43645) exited normally]
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffee3fda0c in lvm_lv_get_name () from /lib64/liblvm2app.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffee3fda0c in lvm_lv_get_name () from /lib64/liblvm2app.so
#1  0x00000000400164e0 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000b22d18 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007ffff000b378 in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) info sharedlibrary liblvm2app.so
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007fffee3fcc20  0x00007fffee4a02c8  Yes (*)     /lib64/liblvm2app.so
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
(gdb) info register
rax            0x0  0
rbx            0xb22d70 11677040
rcx            0xa12590 10560912
rdx            0x0  0
rsi            0x7ffff000bae8   140737219967720
rdi            0xb22d70 11677040
rbp            0x7fffffffdbb0   0x7fffffffdbb0
rsp            0x7fffffffda80   0x7fffffffda80
r8             0x0  0
r9             0xaabc   43708
r10            0x7ffff72947b8   140737340065720
r11            0x7fffee3fd9f0   140737190550000
r12            0x7ffff000b378   140737219965816
r13            0x0  0
r14            0x7fffffffdf10   140737488346896
r15            0xb22d70 11677040
rip            0x7fffee3fda0c   0x7fffee3fda0c <lvm_lv_get_name+28>
eflags         0x10246  [ PF ZF IF RF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
gs             0x0  0
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffdaa0:
 rip = 0x7fffee3fda0c in lvm_lv_get_name; saved rip 0x400164e0
 called by frame at 0x7fffffffdaa8
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffda78, args: 
 Locals at 0x7fffffffda78, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffdaa0
 Saved registers:
  rbx at 0x7fffffffda90, rip at 0x7fffffffda98
(gdb)
```

from this output a possible conslusion would be, that the segmentation fault occurs by the call of the function lvm_lv_get_name.
The strange thing about that is, that i don't call this function.

So I'm at a dead end right now and would appreciate your help.

regards

Comment: Why not do the same as the example and call `lvm_list_vg_names`?

Comment: this is just an short sample. in the project i have a successful call on lvm_list_vg_names. The problem here is, that i need a handle to the vg in order to get further information about the vg. lvm_list_vg_names just returns a linked list of strings.